# Please how do i form a dictionary from a file content that has header sections and body sections?

Tags: python, ordereddict

Given a File with the contents below :

```
******************
* Header title 1
* + trig apple
* + targ beans
* + trig grapes
* + targ berries

* Header title 2
* + trig beans
* + targ joke
* + trig help
* + targ me
```

The above pattern repeats with every header title having a uniq string.
As i read the file i would like to create an ordered dict with keys as the Header titles and values as a list of the lines in the body section. So something like this :

```
d = {
    Header title 1: ['+ trig apple', '+ targ beans', '+ trig grapes', '+ targ berries' ],
    Header title 2: ['+ trig beans', '+ targ joke',  '+ trig grapes', '+ targ berries' ],
      .
      .
      .
    <key>: <value>
}
```

Please i am stuck! My current solution tries to iterate the file line by line to store the values in the list for each header, but i am seeing that it is storing all the body sections for all the headers into the list value for each header. Essentially my solution is not giving what i need.

I indicated above what i tried

Comment: Please show the actual code you tried to write, not just a description of it.

Comment: When you're reading the file, check if the line begins with `*` or `* +`. If it begins with `*` then it's the next dictionary key. If it begins with `* +`, append the rest of the line to the list in that key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will create the file based on your sample input, then read it into an OrderedDict. This assumes headers start with * and records start with * +. It also presupposes that no records occur before the first header is set. You also likely want to clean up your text by removing new lines \n.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

file_content = """* Header title 1
* + trig apple
* + targ beans
* + trig grapes
* + targ berries

* Header title 2
* + trig beans
* + targ joke
* + trig help
* + targ me"""

# Write file
with open("file.txt", "w+") as new_file:
    new_file.write(file_content)

# Read file to ordered dict
d = OrderedDict()
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("* +"):
            # Note this could be unbound, we assume Headers always start with '*'
            # and preceed any records with '* +'
            d[current_key].append(line.replace("* ", ""))
        elif line.startswith("*"):
            current_key = line.replace("* ", "")
            d[current_key] = []
print(d["Header title 1\n"])
print(d["Header title 2\n"])

# ['+ trig apple\n', '+ targ beans\n', '+ trig grapes\n', '+ targ berries\n']
# ['+ trig beans\n', '+ targ joke\n', '+ trig help\n', '+ targ me']
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Jamie. I guess i left a critical part out . There is a record of ****** before the first header occurs. I had a similar logic flow but i am getting extra set of records for each header. I am still working through it.

Comment: I see, you could replace with second `startswith("*")` with `startswith("* ")`. Adding the space afterwards should help ignore cases where ***** occurs

Comment: The flow you suggested worked. I do something a bit different with the records than the problem i originally stated. The part of the question which i omitted was actually the part causing error. I do create a dict of records using the second field in each record as key (Always unique). So i was storing that dict incorrectly. i was supposed to append it.